# Objective C: Using a single object for multiple View Controllers in a simple application

Tags: ios, objective-c

Full disclosure, I'm not a programmer by trade.  I'm actually a resident in a surgery program who developed an interest in programming during my research years which has been fostered by recent increase in Ipad use in clinical practice.  In other words, please forgive any ignorance or bad habits as this isn't my usual field and I've struggled for a while with this problem.

I am writing a small application to do some specific calculations related to my clinical practice.  The basic gist is that I am working with a tabbed application with at least two tabs and separate view controllers for each tab.  For my application I created a single object to do all of the calculation and manage all of the patient data.  My problem lies in that I can't seem find a strategy to have all of the view controllers have access to the instance of the class that I created to do the calculations and manage the data.  I've tried placing the initialization of the instance in the appdelegate m file and importing that into each controller but that gives me multiple errors from repeat declarations.  I've tried placing it in the m file for one view controller and importing it into the second with the same compile errors.  I've tried declaring the instance in the appdelegate header file and importing it but the view controllers don't seem to recognize it.

Anyway, I may be going about this strategy all wrong but any direction on if this is possible or alternate strategies would be appreciated.  Also, maybe I am reading the compiler error incorrectly:

> duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppDelegate._window in:
>       /Users/Joshua/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NutritionAppAlpha-cgnuaytpdjbxqfediwqybepqfbte/Build/Intermediates/NutritionAppAlpha.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/NutritionAppAlpha.build/Objects-normal/i386/AppDelegate.o
>       /Users/Joshua/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NutritionAppAlpha-cgnuaytpdjbxqfediwqybepqfbte/Build/Intermediates/NutritionAppAlpha.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/NutritionAppAlpha.build/Objects-normal/i386/FirstViewController.o
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_AppDelegate in:
>       /Users/Joshua/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NutritionAppAlpha-cgnuaytpdjbxqfediwqybepqfbte/Build/Intermediates/NutritionAppAlpha.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/NutritionAppAlpha.build/Objects-normal/i386/AppDelegate.o
>       /Users/Joshua/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NutritionAppAlpha-cgnuaytpdjbxqfediwqybepqfbte/Build/Intermediates/NutritionAppAlpha.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/NutritionAppAlpha.build/Objects-normal/i386/FirstViewController.o
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_AppDelegate in:
>       /Users/Joshua/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NutritionAppAlpha-cgnuaytpdjbxqfediwqybepqfbte/Build/Intermediates/NutritionAppAlpha.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/NutritionAppAlpha.build/Objects-normal/i386/AppDelegate.o
>       /Users/Joshua/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NutritionAppAlpha-cgnuaytpdjbxqfediwqybepqfbte/Build/Intermediates/NutritionAppAlpha.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/NutritionAppAlpha.build/Objects-normal/i386/FirstViewController.o
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppDelegate._window in:
>       /Users/Joshua/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NutritionAppAlpha-cgnuaytpdjbxqfediwqybepqfbte/Build/Intermediates/NutritionAppAlpha.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/NutritionAppAlpha.build/Objects-normal/i386/AppDelegate.o
>       /Users/Joshua/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NutritionAppAlpha-cgnuaytpdjbxqfediwqybepqfbte/Build/Intermediates/NutritionAppAlpha.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/NutritionAppAlpha.build/Objects-normal/i386/SecondViewController.o
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_AppDelegate in:
>       /Users/Joshua/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NutritionAppAlpha-cgnuaytpdjbxqfediwqybepqfbte/Build/Intermediates/NutritionAppAlpha.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/NutritionAppAlpha.build/Objects-normal/i386/AppDelegate.o
>       /Users/Joshua/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NutritionAppAlpha-cgnuaytpdjbxqfediwqybepqfbte/Build/Intermediates/NutritionAppAlpha.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/NutritionAppAlpha.build/Objects-normal/i386/SecondViewController.o
>   duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_AppDelegate in:
>       /Users/Joshua/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NutritionAppAlpha-cgnuaytpdjbxqfediwqybepqfbte/Build/Intermediates/NutritionAppAlpha.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/NutritionAppAlpha.build/Objects-normal/i386/AppDelegate.o
>       /Users/Joshua/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NutritionAppAlpha-cgnuaytpdjbxqfediwqybepqfbte/Build/Intermediates/NutritionAppAlpha.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/NutritionAppAlpha.build/Objects-normal/i386/SecondViewController.o
>   ld: 6 duplicate symbols for architecture i386 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see in

Comment: you must include your code. or this question will be closed in few minutes.

Comment: Make sure you're importing `AppDelegate.h` and not `AppDelegate.m`.

Comment: see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: This type of error is likely to come up when you have "global" variables in multiple class definitions. Globals don't look much different from static variables (class variables) but they are declared outside of an @interface/@end or @implemenation@end block. The same applies to functions (which are not methods in this case). Although they are defined in separate .m files and therefore not visible to the compiler on compile time (and cannot be detected by the compiler) they are in a global scope. The linker will find duplicates eventually.

Comment: Somewhere, you have `#import "something.m"` instead of `#import "something.h"`.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to deal with this is a shared instance design pattern.  Assuming your class you want to share is named `Calculator`:

```
//Calculator.h
@interface Calculator : NSObject

+ (instancetype)sharedCalculator;

@end
```

To implement the shared instance, we use the `static` keyword to make sure we are always using the same object.

```
//Calculator.m
@implementation

+ (instancetype)sharedCalculator
{
    static Calculator sharedInstance = nil;
    if (!sharedInstance)
    {
        sharedInstance = [[Calculator alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedInstance;
}

@end
```

Now anywhere you need to use the calculator, you just use `[Calculator sharedCalculator]` instead of creating a new instance of the class.

Comment: You should use `dispatch_once` instead of your method. Otherwise, you're right.